# 503 error while connecting to my ec2 elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i deployed my war onto elastic beanstalk and I am running many connections from an outside pc onto the service trying to load test.

I am getting this error

```
[ERROR] 2011-08-09 07:03:52,134 could not process CompanyBridgePromoResult
```

com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST [url] returned a response status of 503
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:576)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:72)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:506)
    at com.icon.sa.ac.JerseyAdminClient.itemSearch(JerseyAdminClient.java:507)
    at com.icon.sa.bridge.google.GoogleShoppingFtpCompanyBridge.handle(GoogleShoppingFtpCompanyBridge.java:1)
    at com.icon.sa.bridge.BasicCompanyBridge$1.run(BasicCompanyBridge.java:86)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am running c3p0 as my connection pool. I cannot see any errors on the server and its healthy.

Does amazon have a service to block out certain connections after too many connections from the same host? I tested locally I did not have any of these problems.

Comment: I just got this error on a single-instance beanstalk. I'm able to connect to the EC2 instance directly, but the load balancer returns 503 for some reason. I don't have any load, no connections.